# Save a HTML table to database after order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to save a HTML table to database after ordering it w/ `jQuery` UI `Drag'n'Drop`.

In my database table I have **`ID`** and **`Name fields`**.

The important to me is Name appear in ordered way, not the `ID` stays the same.

Anyone can help me?

**EDIT :**

Let me show the code:

```
<table>
<% @Clients.each do |c| %>
    <tr>
        <td>c.id</td>
        <td>c.name</td>
    </tr>
 <% end %>
 </table>
```

I'm using jQuery drag and drop to reorder this table

After hit 'Save' button, I want to save the table as it is.

e.g.

1 - Mary
2 - John
3 - Chris

After reorder and save, I want the next time 1 reload this table looks like:

2 - John
1 - Mary
3 - Chris

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: I would be half tempted to add an order field to the database and save that rather than the html.

Comment: Why don't you just use ActiveRecord/SQL to order by name when you get the data? Could you describe your problem and ordering more exactly?

Comment: Why do you need to save a raw HTML do database? It seems like you are doing something wrong from the very beginning

Answer (score -1):

You need not store the data in an order in the database, you can always use 'order by' clause and fetch the results in ascending or descending order to display them in the required pages.

Comment: "Order" here means like "make order for something in shop", not selection ordering